# mysql2 gem support updatable record

Tags: mysql, ruby

Does the mysql2 gem support a Microsoft-Access-like, update-able recordset?

Something like:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :database=> "db")

results = client.query("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...;")

results.each do |row|

  # additional processing to calculate `a value`

  # set a column's value and update
  row["column_a"] = 'a value'
  row.save

end

client.close()
```

If not, what's my best alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not. You can either go with what Arup suggested or use the gem [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) to achieve similar functionality

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.connect('mysql2://root@localhost/db')

class Post < Sequel::Model
end

Post.where(category: 'ruby').each do |post|
  post.title = 'StackOverflow'
  post.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *RAW* sql as

```
require 'mysql'

begin
    con = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", 
                             :username => "root", 
                             :database=> "db"
                             )   
    con.query "UPDATE table_name SET column_a = 'a value' WHERE <criterion>"
    puts "The query has affected #{con.affected_rows} rows" 
rescue Mysql::Error => e
    puts e    
ensure
    con.close if con
end
```

[For `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE`](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlrubytutorial/) statements there is a method called `#rows_affected`. This method returns the *number of rows affected by these three statements*.

Look at the [Test case examples](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/master/spec/mysql2/client_spec.rb#L807-L808) of the [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) Gem official link :

```
it "#last_id should return a Fixnum, the from the last INSERT/UPDATE" do
  @client.query "INSERT INTO lastIdTest (blah) VALUES (%s)" % [ client.escape(1234) ]
  @client.affected_rows.should eql(1)
  @client.query "UPDATE lastIdTest SET blah=4321 WHERE id=%s" % [ client.escape(1) ]
  @client.affected_rows.should eql(1)
end
```

Comment: The `mysql2` driver is not intended to be used directly. It's very difficult to write proper, secure code without a lot of extra work.

Comment: @tadman I cheked their Test examples.. They also wrote using RAW sql.. So.. :-) But I was not aware of OP is flexible with other Gems too.

Comment: Every time I've tried to use `mysql2` directly I've been appalled how hard it is to write properly escaped SQL. If you need a light-weight layer, Sequel is great and unobtrusive.

Comment: @tadman Ok.. I was not aware of.. Better then delete my answer. :-)

Comment: As an academic point, you might want to demonstrate how tricky it is to properly escape values. Will serve as useful example of why not to use the driver.

Comment: @tadman Could you edit ? I never had met such situations.. in my short span of programming time... I am still crawling.. :-(

Comment: You seem to be doing pretty well. Added a small modification to demonstrate.

Comment: @tadman That's my advance learning. Thanks for teaching me. I was not aware of this *trick* except the method `String#%`. :) Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

If you want update number of records try this, it's simple:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'mysql2'

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  Post.where(category: 'ruby').update_attributes(title: 'Stackoverflow')
end
```

Comment: That's ActiveRecord, not `mysql2`. While ActiveRecord can use that driver, they are two different things.